# INSERT INTO table VALUES.. vs INSERT INTO table SET Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-5.1

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
"insert into visits set source = 'http://google.com' and country = 'en' and ref = '1234567890';"
```

The query looks good to me and it prints a warning:

```
1 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s): 1364 Field 'country' doesn't have a default value 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'http://google.com'
```

And the info isn't stored as expected:

```
id , ref , bnid, source, country
'5', NULL, NULL, '0'   , ''
```

If I run the normal syntax like:

```
insert into visits (source,country,ref) values('http://google.com','en','1234567890');
```

I get the expected result:

```
'6', '1234567890', NULL, 'http://google.com', 'en'
```

The first syntax (insert set) was working in previous server. Now I changed to one with cpanel and it doesn't. It's the second time this week I get this problem in two different VPS with cpanel so I'm guessing it should be the version number or mysql config.

**Mysql Version: 5.1.63-cll**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bnid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove 'and' from the insert query

```
insert into visits set source = 'http://google.com' , country = 'en' , ref = '1234567890'
```

Comment: upps I'm quite ashamed of myself... Sorry

Comment: don't worry, happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 3):

When using `INSERT...SET`, separate the fields using `,`, not `AND`.

```
INSERT INTO visits SET source = 'http://google.com', country = 'en', ref = '1234567890';
```